# Copy directory from another project during build

Tags: java, maven

In project A I have a dependency to project B which has the CSS resources directory.
Due to some framework issues I need to copy the CSS directory to project A during the build. How to do it? The css directory is inside src/main/resources/css therefore it goes to /css inside the .jar

Answer (score 0):

No need to copy because [Servlet 3.0 Specs](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf) sais in part 3.6, you can place the css in `META-INF/resources` into the jar of your project B.

It works great except `maven-tomcat-plugin`.

Comment: i think it goes into classpath, its  not copied

Comment: As i said: No need to copy. Read page 106! `static content can also be packaged in a JAR file with the content listed above packaged in the META-INF/resources directory of the jar file. The JAR file can then be included in the WEB-INF/lib directory of the web application.`

Answer (score 0):

This is where the file ends up:

```
<outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/blah</outputDirectory>
```

This is where it is copied from:

```
<directory>src/main/otherresources</directory>
```

There would be an  or  tag to tell the file name(s)

**Multiples**

You need multiple executions with different ids for multiple folders:

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions. But before you have to know the path from project A to project B.
You can use the [maven resource plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html).
There's a goal to copy a resource to an output directory.

Or, you can use the maven ant plugin.
Here is an example : http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/how-to-run-ant-targets-with-maven.html